# Remote Desktop to localhost on Startup & two active accounts

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have 2 accounts on my machine one is the foreground account (console) that runs media center software.

The other account runs other programs I use in a remote desktop session.

I have enabled group policy to force 1 account per RDP session to stop applications starting multiple times.

But I cannot create a startup task to login the 2nd user when the 1st account autologin takes place on boot.

Is there a way to create a user session without RDP?

Everytime I try to RDP to the machine locally with or without console flag i get this error **"Your computer could not connect to another console session"**

Comment: What OS are we talking here?

Comment: I think you need to explain what your trying to do here, does this relate to the other question you post about only running an application once?

Comment: Why can't you just let Windows create the session when you first connect to it when you want to use it. Like you normally do.

Comment: In terms of the username/password thing - Windows only allows for storing one username/password combination for logging into a server.  So if you need two profiles to automatically  ogin concurrently, unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same position as you. I have my media center login which logs in automatically and which starts uTorrent up as well.

Now I am able to login as a remote user using another account, but I am unable to configure/view uTorrent.

The simplest solution is to give the hostname as 127.0.0.2 in mstsc. This will allow you to logon to another RDP session on the same machine.

However, I am stuck trying to run it from a command line. The first login works, but it is unable to save the username/password in a saved session.

Hope this works for you. Please revert if you have any suggestoins on this,

Comment: Are you talking about http://www.techbuzz.in/connect-remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-client-to-localhost.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You want stuff to be running locally on console & then RDP remotely & not affect the console session? 
Or 
You want to have 2 login accounts that can RDP remotley into the desktop & take over the console?

For the latter, then RDP should do the job, make sure you have firewall rules setup to have exceptions for TCP 3389 which RDP uses.

Applications like winVNC and [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) always log you into the console session, maybe try these?  RDP has much better performance if you can get it to work.

If you want the former, then your out of luck. I think MS has put this in as a limitation on windows desktops like XP/Vista so you dont end up using them as terminal servers.

You could do with with windows server?   There may be OS level hack to get this to work in a desktop OS, but i have never had the need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

- [How to Enable Concurrent Sessions in Windows 7 RTM](http://missingremote.com/guide/how-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-rtm)
- [How to Enable Concurrent Sessions in Vista](http://missingremote.com/guide/how-enable-concurrent-sessions-vista)

Comment: Sort of, I have already completed this step, but now I want one user to create an RDP session to localhost as the second user.

Comment: you want to rdp into your own computer?

Comment: Yes so I can create 2 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit of a stretch, but have you looked at something like AutoIt (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for this?  Basically autologin your console account per what you are doing now, then make a startup script in that profile that will RDP to itself with the other account.  Have no idea if this will actually work, but that's the only way I can think of to bootstrap the way you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm missing something but to me RDP to localhost doesn't make sense and shouldn't even be possible, because it would allow the creation of an infinitely recursive process.

Comment: Makes no less sense than a terminal session as another use or a virtual machine, I want to have 2 sessions running on the 1 pc. I can do this if I connect from another PC.

Comment: I guess it would work if you logged in as a 2nd user and thus the startup script didn't exist in the 2nd user...

Comment: You can't login from a localhost to itself with the same account.  You can login with a different account.  Works fine.  (I use that feature all the time as defacto sudo-type functionality on some Windows servers usually unprivileged but need to level up, rdesktop to same server, do task, exit back out.)  If you do try to login to the same username locally, it blocks the login and throws an error.\